# How to query database before submit button is pressed

Tags: javascript, ajax, coldfusion

I have a question. I have a coldfusion form that ask for some basic input

```
 <label class="ricRequired">ID<label><br />
 <input type="text" id="tid" name="tid" size="30" maxlength="10" class="ricValidate"    ric:required="yes" ric:format="integer"  />
```

The form has a submit button at the end. I want to check if the user exist in the database once the user enter his/her id. How can I do this? Is there an easier way than using ajax?

Comment: Ajax can only be avoided if you are willing to have a page (re)load.

Comment: how would I do the page reload and keep the form fields thats already populated?

Comment: if would involve "POST"ing the variables and then repopulating the input fields with them. for the most part, an ajax will greatly simplify things.have you worked with it before?

Comment: No. It looks like that is what I will have to do. Any suggestions on starting points?

Comment: try this, https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax   if you have any problems post it here.

Comment: You could have javascript write to a coldfusion page in an iframe and write back to the parent, but I'm not sure it will be easier than ajax.

Comment: There may be 'other' ways to do this that do not involve AJAX, but none of them will be 'easier'.

Comment: Follow this Tutorial as this Uses the Jquery and Coldfusion to detect the username is available or not, You can also checked the usreid. http://eisabainyo.net/weblog/2009/05/28/check-username-availability-using-ajax-and-jquery/

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure exactly what you need but I'll give you an example of how I would do it.

**Action/HTML Page**

```
<html>
    <head>  
        <script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.11.1/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $('#tid').autocomplete({
                    source: function(query, response) {
                        $.ajax({
                            url: "funcEntity.cfc?method=userSearch&returnformat=json",
                            dataType: "json",
                            data: {
                                searchPhrase: query.term
                            },
                            success: function(result) {
                                $("#someDiv").html(result);
                            }
                        });
                    }
                });
        </script>

    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="someDiv">
            <!--- displays message --->
        </div>
        <div>
            <form name="someForm" method="POST">
                <label class="ricRequired">ID<label><br />
                <input type="text" id="tid" name="tid" size="30" maxlength="10" class="ricValidate" ric:required="yes" ric:format="integer"  />
            </form>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**Function/funcEntity.cfc**

```
<cfcomponent>

<cffunction name="userSearch" access="remote">
    <cfargument name="searchPhrase" />
    <cfquery name="usernameQuery" datasource="yourDatasource">
        SELECT username
        FROM someTable
        WHERE username = <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" value="#searchPhrase#">
    </cfquery>
    <cfif usernameQuery.recordCount GT "0">
        <cfset var content = "This username already exists.">
    <cfelse>
        <cfset var content = "This username is available.">
    </cfif>
    <cfreturn content>
</cffunction>

</cfcomponent>
```

This is not tested code and I'm sort of in a hurry. I used autocomplete so it checks the database as you type.